# Create a dictionary of a model?

Tags: c#, linq

It's quite hard for me to explain this, but I will give it a go.

Objective:

Create a LINQ query that will return a dictionary of data. However it must be a dictionary of the model which I am using.

View Model:

```
public class ValueBySupplierAndClaimTypeViewModel : ReportViewModel
{
    public IQueryable<ValueBySupplierAndClaimTypeModel> ReportData {get; set; }
    public TotalValueBySupplierAndClaimTypeModel ReportTotalData { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> DictionaryData { get; set; }

    public string output { get; set; }
}
```

Interface:

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> DictData;

TotalValueBySupplierAndClaimTypeModel GetTotalValueBySupplierAndClaimType(
    int ClientID, int ReviewPeriodID, int StatusCategoryID);
```

SQL Repository:

```
public TotalValueBySupplierAndClaimTypeModel GetTotalValueBySupplierAndClaimType(int ClientID, int ReviewPeriodID, int StatusCategoryID)
{
    var rt =
        this.GetValueBySupplierAndClaimType(ClientID, ReviewPeriodID, StatusCategoryID);

    TotalValueBySupplierAndClaimTypeModel x = new TotalValueBySupplierAndClaimTypeModel()
    {
        NormalTotal = rt.Sum(c=>c.Normal) ?? 0,
        QueryTotal = rt.Sum( c => c.Query) ?? 0,
        StrongTotal = rt.Sum( c => c.Strong) ?? 0
    };

    return x;
}
```

I'm really not sure how to do this. Can anybody help?

Comment: Use [`ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @DavidG It wont let me use .ToDictionary

Comment: How exactly will it not let you?!

Comment: @DavidG Because it's not an IEnumerable. Its only an instance of my model

Comment: So what exactly do you want in this dictionary?

Comment: @DavidG I want to create a dictionary of my model. Basically my model will return 3 values. I want these totals to be in a format like the following: [Category: "Test1", Value: 100}, Category: "Test2", Value: 200}, Category: "Test3", Value: 100}]

Comment: Can't do LINQ on a single instance object. You need an IEnumerable, at least. That being said, there's still room for some code cleverness here.

Answer (score 0):

I have this function that converts an object to a dictionary. It gets all the properties of the class, as the dictionary's keys. May be you can modify it to meet your needs:

```
    public Dictionary<string, object> ConvertClassToDict(object classToConvert)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = classToConvert.GetType().GetProperties();
        List<string> propertiesNames = properties.Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
        foreach (var propName in propertiesNames)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = properties.First(srcProp => srcProp.Name == propName);
            var value = property.GetValue(classToConvert, null);
            result.Add(propName, value);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The argument classToConvert, is just an instance of any class.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @lukiller's answer, but with LINQ:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> MapToDictionary(object instance)
{
    if(instance == null) return null;
    return instance.GetType()
                   .GetProperties()
                   .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, 
                                 p => p.GetValue(instance));
}
```

For example, let's suppose we have the following class:

```
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

We can print it like this (one line):

```
MapToDictionary(new User()
{
    Username = "mcicero",
    Password = "abc123"
}).ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i.Key, i.Value));
```

This prints out:

```
Username: mcicero
Password: abc123
```